# How to do down a directory? Opposite of "../../"

Tags: php, directory

Is there an opposite method of going up a directory?

Example:

```
../../folder-name/file.php
```

The above will go up 2 directories then search for `/folder-name/file.php`.

Example Usage:

```
require_once('../../folder-name/file.php');
```

I'm trying something like...

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../../folder-name/file.php');
```

I know I can use the asterisk wild card in the `glob()` function.

But I don't want to do a search that function does when I know the direct path. I also have no need to return an array which `glob()` does.

Glob will accept the wild card asterisk like so...

```
glob('/*/*/folder-name/file.php');
```

But I see this is an exclusive operation to glob() (and maybe other functions) but not available in general for all path specifications.

So something like below doesn't work...

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/*/*/folder-name/file.php');
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Is there a way to make php go down to the next directory when that directory is not known?

Comment: PHP wouldn't know if you wanted to require `1/1/folder-name/file.php` or `1/2/folder-name/file.php` or both. You could iterate over the glob result and require each..

Comment: You can't go down unless you know where you want to go down to. You can always go up because there's only one parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `glob()` and then pass the result to `require_once`:

```
$files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/*/*/folder-name/file.php');
if (count($files) == 1) {
    require_once($files[0]);
} else {
    die("Can't find file.php");
}
```

This checks that there's only one `file.php`, because if there are more then it's not clear which one should be used.

Comment: Hi. I came up with the upper part portion of this method already. But I was trying to scale back from it because I noticed that glob was search whole directories, then getting the matching. So my question is, which I should have maybe i asked, is what is your take on this function if it was ran many many times? I feel like glob performing such a wide search, calling this function within each file of mine will be too much way unneeded overhead. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Oh, haha! I have an idea now from this, which surely will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
$handle = opendir("./");

while($file = readdir($handle)){
  if(is_dir($file)){
    print "directory found<br>";
  }
}
```

and make a function for the check and traverse of a dir,